# Empty HTTP response (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http, get, request

so I'm pretty new to Python (3.4) and I'm trying to build a tester that makes requests to the GAE and returns the body of each response. However with the code I have, using urllib.request, I keep getting an empty response (The response would be b'', it's in bytes.) I tried to decode it but it's still empty. But the headers seem fine and I'm getting a 200 code. Could this be a problem with the server?
Code:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
import urllib.response
import time

url = 'insert url here'
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
iters = 1
miters = 10
delay = 0
bk = False
for i in range(5):
    if bk == False:
        for j in range(miters):
            if bk == False:
                for k in range(iters):
                    try:
                        with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
                            headers = response.info()
                            resp = response.read()
                            resp2 = resp.decode('base64','strict')
                            print('date of request = ', headers['date'])
                            print(str(resp2))
                        time.sleep(delay)
                    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
                        blah blah various error handlers
                        bk = True
                        break
            else:
                break

            iters += 1
            print('iterations increased!')
            time.sleep(30)
        delay += 0.25
        print('delay increased!')
        iters = 1
        time.sleep(30)
    else:
        break
```

I looked into TCPDump but it seems way over my head. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why do you think it's a problem? if the server does not return anything on the body, this is expected. You can check the content length in the response header.

Comment: true, content length is zero. i think it's a back end problem.

Comment: May be you should show us your back end handler code to suggest a fix for the issue.